# Produce and Consume SOAP web service using spring

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I am working on building a secure SOAP web service using spring. Although, it is a common topic, I would like to make a conscious start by ensuring that I am up to date with the latest approach or technology or framework that I am using. The secure web service that I will be producing will be exposed in internet.

Please suggest the best practice to build a secure web service and recommendations that you may have in terms of the framework to you.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/